# node.js server stop working after a while on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I have a node.js app running on my laptop (Windows 10).
Basically it sends http requests periodically.

I noticed that my app will be paused after a certain period if there are no activities on my laptop. It can only be resumed again when I click the screen(node.js command screen)

Comment: can you post code?

Comment: what are the battery saving options on your laptop?  Disable all that stuff?

Comment: You could use forever for example, it would ensure that a given script runs continuously. https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can run your Node program as a service.

You can try using NSSM:

- http://nssm.cc/

I would also recommend tools like `forever` or `jesus` or `supervisor`:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jesus
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/supervisor

if you said that your program terminates and you want to keep it running but since it keeps running but gets suspended than maybe running it as a service in Windows would help.

You can also try those modules that try to keep your system awake:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/stay-awake
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/win-wake

Answer (score 0):

As Manuel said, forever is a great way to keep a node app running. Scripts can time out for multiple reasons, the inactivity could be one. It might be wise to store REPL commands. Maybe [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monitor)?